# Get Value from Database without EvenListener

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I make a void to get some values from database but don't refresh this data everytime the database changes, this is the void I have:

```
private void getUser() {



    userInformationsList.clear();
    DatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            userID = user.getUid();
            nameID = dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(userID).child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Lat = dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(userID).child("Coordenates/Rute/Lat").getValue(String.class);
            Lng = dataSnapshot.child("Users").child(userID).child("Coordenates/Rute/Lng").getValue(String.class);
            DataSnapshot dS = dataSnapshot.child("Coordenate").child(Lat).child(Lng);
            toolbar.setTitle(nameID);
            for(DataSnapshot Ds : dS.getChildren()) {
                Object key = Ds.getKey();
                String StringKey = String.valueOf(key);
                getname(StringKey);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this,"Error 404",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

It works fine when I call it but it triggers whenever the database is changed. I think is because the void `onDataChange` or the `ValueEventListener`.

I am wandering if there is other method to call the DataSnapshot.

Answer (score 0):

To only read the data from the database once and not get notified of updates, register your listener with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`. So:

```
DatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

This and much more is explained in the [Firebase documentation on reading data from the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_data_once).

Comment: It doesn´t work, still trigger every time the dat is change.

Comment: That seems odd. `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` fires "immediately" for the current value and then stop listening. I've never seen it work differently than that, so most likely it's in the way you set it up. With the code you shared, the `onDataChange` will get called every time you call `getUser`.

Comment: Because I want t call it when a button is press but not when the database is change. any idea how can I implement?